# requirejs require text! with relative path cause unnormalized error on iphone, bet works on emulator

Tags: javascript, iphone, cordova, requirejs

I am using requirejs with phonegap, and load some text file in module definition like this

```
define(['text!../configuration/systemcore.cfg', //config files
        'text!../language/cn.systemcore.lang', //languagefiles
        'Configuration', 'DatabaseHandler', 'Language', //framework js 
        'FileHandler', 'NotificationHandler',  
        'BaseModule' //base classes
        ], 
        function(cfg, lang,
                Configuration, DatabaseHandler, Language, FileHandler, NotificationHandler,
                BaseModule) {
```

Everything works fine in the ios emulator, but once loaded into ios device, it causes

unnormalized error on text file which leads to load module timeout, why...

Comment: Ok, I did some more research, it seem this error is somehow connected with the text! not recognised, perhaps the text loader plugin somehow is not functioning in the ios device environment.

Comment: Ok, some more research, weird that on emulator, loader plugin text.js is automatically loaded, but on ios it is not.. weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I added text : 'path/to/text.js' in the requirejs.config({ patch : {...}}) and it solved the problem. It is still weird how can it work before in the emulator when I dont specifically point to the text.js

Comment: The reason is valid. I was facing similar issue. I managed to fix my problem by configuring the path accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this answer is not a solution for this specific question, but however this topic I've found searching for similar problem: unnormalized error and load timeout in console, so might be useful to post it here.

Text plugin seems to work incorrectly when referenced two times with different paths (from my experience).

E.g. if you reference it with full path first:

```
define(["js/libs/text!somefile.html"], ...)
```

and then config requireJS path and use alias to it:

```
require.config({paths: {
  "text": "js/libs/text.js"
}});

define(["text!somefile.html"], ...)
```

it makes the same module to be loaded twice, and the second `define` causes an error. Correct me if I am wrong.